# I haven't seen any aliens in my life - does it imply aliens exists?

Tags: meaning

Alien could be any word. "I haven't seen any aliens in my life". Does saying like this imply interlocutor thinks aliens exists?

[difference between "can do nothing" and "cannot do anything"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457303/difference-between-can-do-nothing-and-cannot-do-anything?newreg=0873331526234b8bbf6245c940128267) Just  in case: "I have seen no aliens." - same meaning?

P.S. That might look like question on language in general, however AFAIK different cultures can interpret phrases differently, so I asked here.

Comment: We'd usually  say, "I've never seen an alien." The word 'never' here implies 'in my life.' No, it doesn't suggest they exist. We might say, "I have seen no aliens" if there was a possibility of there being aliens in the vicinity.

Comment: (1) I'll switch to 'extraterrestrial/s' rather than the more polysemous 'alien/s' (most of us have seen people from a different country). And leaving aside the domains of religion, philosophy, and nuclear physics, I doubt there are many reasonably common words with putative referents.  (2) "I haven't seen any extraterrestrials in my life" would be informed by pragmatics. Most people hearing this (assuming reasonable context) would judge the speaker's view on the likelihood that ets exist _from_ previous statements, and tone. Wistful, hopeful? Neutral, sceptical? Scorning, dismissive?

Comment: "Does saying like this imply interlocutor thinks aliens exists?" The opposite, it implies that the interlocutor thinks that aliens may not exist, without definitively ruling out the possibility.

Comment: Nothing is implied either way. "I haven't seen Africa in my life." "I haven't seen a five-headed leprechaun with enviable halitosis in my life." I haven't seen Africa, no doubt in my mind it exists. Leprechauns? Not with 5 heads, no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I haven't seen any aliens in my life - does it imply aliens exists?

No. As it stands, it is a simple statement about the speaker's experience.

Compare

"I haven't seen any viruses/bald eagles/ in my life."

Comment: One could also say equally correctly, "I've never seen a pregnant stag in my life," even though that refers to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ohwilleke It would still be merely a statement about the speaker's experience.